# Core Data helper class returning object nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to clean up my code a little and I've had the idea to create a little helper class to save and fetch data from core data.

I do the NSFechtRequest from within the helper class like this:

```
- (NSArray *)fetchDataOutOfDBWithEntity:(NSString *)description
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HealthData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    return results;

}
```

This just returns a `NSArray` as it should be if you use `executeFetchRequest:error:`

I call this function out of a UICollectionsViewController's `viewDidLoad` method like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    DatabaseHelper *helper = [[DatabaseHelper alloc] init];
    NSArray *array = [helper fetchDataOutOfDBWithEntity:@"HealthData"];
    dataInHealth = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
}
```

The weird thing now is that dataInHealth contains information. I can print them out and I can see the `NSManagedObjects` (via breakpoints) within the Array I returned but when I want to insert the information into the collectionView it just doesn't do anything or throws some crazy exceptions (depending on what I'm doing).

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    KalenderCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    HealthData *object = [dataInHealth objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.stepCount.text = object.stepCount;


    return cell;
}
```

`object.stepCount`is just nil and all the other properties I have stay the same. Why can't I access my properties. When I chance nothing except the fetching from within the viewDidLoad instead of the helper class everything works out of the box.

There is data in that NSArray. Why can't I access it?

Comment: Could you include the exact error that is occurring?

Comment: Hi Constantin you say that it generates exceptions, could you post them?

Comment: Every object I try to access returns nil. Error only under certain circumstances; because i use ... doubleValue]; and it just crashes because it gets NSNull

Answer (score 1):

Try making the DatabaseHelper object into a property, I think your Managed Object Context is being released when viewDidLoad ends its execution, releasing also all of the ManagedObjects you fetched through it.

Comment: or singleton, or hold the moc in the application class :)

Comment: Can't be. The array is defined as (nonatomic, strong).

Comment: I can print the array from `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Comment: It seem that I just can't access any property in it via KVC

Comment: Sure go ahead. By the way, @geo is right, you just have to hold the moc reference, doesn't have to be a property.